# What is $\mathbb{C}[xy]/\langle x\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x \rangle$?

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, 
and consider 
$$R=\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[xy]}{\langle x\rangle } \subseteq \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle x\rangle }\cong \mathbb{C}[y].$$

> Is $R\cong \mathbb{C}$?
>
> Now considering $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]$, is 
>   $$
> \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[xy,zy,wy]}{\langle y \rangle} \cong \mathbb{C}
> $$
>   true?

Comment: Instead of <, > use \langle, \rangle. This will make the spacing appropriate.

Comment: What do you even mean by this notation? $x$ isn't an element of $\mathbb{C}[xy]$. Do you mean $(x) \cap \mathbb{C}[xy]$ (where $(x)$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: $(x) \cap \mathbb{C}[xy]=(xy)$, so $R=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).